# python3.5.i cant install third-party libraries for python by using instructions " python setup.py install"

Tags: python-3.5

When I tried to install third-party libraries for python3.5,something is wrong like that

```
E:\IE\pycocotools-2.0.0>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

the `setup.py` is from:https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi 
and i want to install cocoAPI to use coco dataSets.

addtions:1 .i had installed vs2017(vc++ environment) in my computer

Comment: i ran it in cmd
E:\IE\pycocotools-2.0.0>python setup.py build running
build running
build_py running
build_ext 
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Did you try the installation command from the README on that page? `pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI`

Comment: thanks for responsing.i just impoved py3.5 to py3.6 and tried again.Luckily,it succeed! i still didnt know why i couldnt install the cocoapi for py3.5....